# Versioning executable and modifying it in runtime

Tags: c++, c, binary, io, versioning

What I'm trying to do is to sign my compiled executable's first 32 bytes  with a version signature, say "1.2.0" and I need to modify this signature in *runtime*, keeping in mind that:

- this will be done by the executable itself
- the executable resides on the client side, meaning no recompilation is possible
- using an external file to track the version instead of encoding it in the binary itself is also not an option
- the solution has to be platform-independent; I'm aware that Windows/VC allows you to version an executable using a .rc resource, but I'm unaware of an equivalent for Mac (maybe Info.plist?) and Linux

The solution in my head was to write the version signature in the first or last 32 bytes of the binary (which I didn't figure out *how* to do yet) and then I'll modify those bytes when I need to. Sadly it's not that simple as I'm trying to modify the same binary that I'm executing.

If you know of how I can do this, or of a cleaner/mainstream solution for this problem, I'd be very grateful. FWIW, the application is a *patcher/launcher* for a game; I chose to encode the version in the patcher itself instead of the game executable as I'd like it to be self-contained and target-independent.

**Update**: from your helpful answers and comments, I see that messing with the header/footer of the binary is not the way to go. But regarding the write permission for the running users, the game has to be patched one way or another and the game files need to be modified, there's no way to circumvent that: to update the game, you'll need admin privileges.

I would opt for using an external file to hold the signature, and modify that with every update, but I can't see how I can guard against the user spoofing with that file: if they mess up the version numbers, how can I detect which version I'm running?

**Update2**: Thanks for all your answers and comments, in truth there are 2 ways to do this: either use an external resource to track the version or embed it in the main application's binary itself. I could choose only 1 answer on SO so I did the one I'm going with, although it's not the only one. :-)

Comment: Are you trying to change the signature on disk on in memory?

Comment: Has it occurred to you that executable might be using those bytes itself?

Comment: @Seth: On disk, how else would it persist after the process is terminated? @Neil: Totally, that's sort of why I'm asking, can I "reserve" those bytes or specify where they're written when I compile it?

Comment: What you want to do isn't possible to do portably.  Consider my situation, using Linux: I install all game launchers under a special 'game' user account.  That account doesn't have write permission to the executable launcher.  I don't run the game under the account I use to do the install.

Comment: @Heath: I see, so running as the 'game' user, you're able to modify all the game files but not the actual executable? So instead I should be patching the game executable and not the launcher?

Comment: The "first 32 bytes" part is a bit problematic. AFAIK, the Microsoft PE format (i.e. Windows .exe files) use all of these bytes for their own stuff. If you overwrite it with your own, you may break it.

Comment: @amireh: No, the 'game' user isn't able to modify any of the game files created by the installation.  If the game goes on to create a file (e.g., high scores) within that user home directory, it will work.  But it won't be able to modify any of the files put on disk during install, nor can it write outside that game user home directory.

Comment: @amireh, a typical non-root UNIX user would probably not have write access for the game executable files themselves, as well as to most of the shared game files. He would only have write access to user-specific game files (e.g. save games) on his own home folder. Actually that should also be the case for any normal Vista or Windows 7 installation where UAC is enabled and the game files live under the Program Files directory.

Comment: If you are using Windows, and are using Windows installer to deliver your app, then any patches will checksum the app and only modify it if it is recognised. Presumably the same facilities are available on package managers on other platforms. Writing your own package manager is a mugs game. This isn't 1954 anymore, you don't have to write everything from scratch yourself! If you have to write your own (and don't!) then don't bother with extra files, just checksum or hash the executable before you attempt to patch it.

Comment: @David: most online games have self-updating facilities, it's not realistic to expect users to keep installing patches themselves, that's why developers have to create their own launchers/patchers. The reason I'm rolling my own is because I want a unified tool across all the platforms I'm targeting. I haven't found any existing solution to this nor resources about this aspect of deployment, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: if you want to do it yourself stay well clear of program files folder and install somewhere inside user profile to avoid uac, and similarly on unix like platforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is meant to patch a game, why not embed the version in there while you're at it? You can use a string like @Juliano shows and modify that from the patcher while the game is not running - which should be the case if you're currently patching anyways. :P

---

**Edit**: If you're working with Visual Studio, it's really easy to embed such a string in the executable with a `#pragma comment`, according to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

```
#pragma comment(user, "Version: 1.4.1")
```

Since the second argument is a simple string literal, it can be concatenated, and I'd have the version in a simple `#define`:

```
// somehwere
#define MY_EXE_VERSION "1.4.1"
// somewhere else
#pragma comment(user, "Version: " MY_EXE_VERSION)
```

Comment: I've just opened World of Warcraft's game binary - not the launcher, in a hex editor and it indeed HAS the version embedded there. Thus I believe your answer is the way to go, although my requirement was to not mess with the app code itself, but keep it in the launcher instead.

Comment: @amireh: See my edit, I found a nice solution for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

Modern Windows versions will not allow you to update an installed program file unless you're running with administrator privileges. I believe all versions of Windows block modifications to a running file altogether; this is why you're forced to reboot after an update. I think you're asking for the impossible.

Comment: So saving the version in an external file is the way to go? I'm afraid of users spoofing with the file and I'll have no way to detect that, then the whole patching process will get broken.

Comment: Can't they spoof the exe file as well? Users can hack everything if they really want to. You can only make it harder for them, but not impossible, and many times this anti-user protection **will** come at the price of cross-platform compatibility. If you really want to make the version info hard to mess with in a cross-platform way, cryptographically sign the version number together with a hash of all the patched files for that version.

Comment: Definitely. In truth, I can just as well save it as plain text, after all if they mess with it, the client won't be validated and they will end up missing out on the patches, and keeping it as plain text makes it easier to fix actually. I just wonder how others do it, like Blizzard's launchers.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be a bit of a challenge, for a number of reasons.  First, writing to the first N bytes of the binary is likely to step on the binary file's header information, which is used by the program loader to determine where the code & data segments, etc. are located within the file.  This will be different on different platforms (see the [ELF format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) and [executable format comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats))--there are a lot of different binary format standards.

Assuming you can overcome that one, you're likely to run afoul of security/antivirus systems if you start modifying a program's code at runtime.  I don't believe most current operating systems will allow you to overwrite a currently-running executable.  At the very least, they might allow you to do so with elevated permissions--not likely to be present while gaming.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give just some ideas on how to do this.

I think it's not possible to change some arbitrary bytes in the executable without side effects. To overcome this, I would create some string in your source code, like:

```
char *Version = "Version: AA.BB.CC";
```

I don't know if this is a rule, but you can look for this string in your binary code (open it in a text editor and you will see). So, you search and change this bytes for your version number in the binary file. Probably, their position will vary each time you compile the application, so this it is possible only if that location is not a problem for you.

Because the file is being used (it's running), you have to launch an external program that would do this. After modifying the file, this external program could relaunch the original application.

The version will be stored in your binary code in some part. Is that useful? How will you retrieve the version number?

Comment: That is useful. I can binary scan the file for the string. However, now that I read your answer, I see that my initial design is flawed: the launcher itself was made to patch the *game*, I shouldn't be using it for this. I'll just save the version in some external file and use that.